# Pentaho : BUG admin UI wont display users list

Tags: pentaho

I replicated a pentaho installation on new virtual machines (1 Tomcat server with pentaho 5.2 and 1 postgresql 9.3).

Everything works, we can login, work, etc... except admin UI who can get XML response of the user list, it's an empty XML list... the API URL call by UI is : https://domain.name/pentaho/api/userroledao/users

Can you help me to find the next step to resolve the problem ? Thanks

[image: IMAGE PENTAHO BUG]

Comment: Can you tell me what is specified at below location... /biserver/Pentaho-solutions/system/repository.spring.properties          singleTenantAdminDefaultAuthorityName=Whichvalue?

Comment: I found that : 
singleTenantAdminDefaultAuthorityName=Administrator

Comment: then it is proper only.

Comment: Yes, that seems correct.